# R - Extracting information from list of lists of data.frames

Tags: r, list, dataframe, subset

I have two needs, both connected to a dataset similar to the reproducible one below. I have a list of 18 entities, each composed of a list of 17-19 data.frames. Reproducible dataset follows (there are matrices instead of data.frames, but I do not suppose that makes a difference):

```
test <- list(list(matrix(10:(50-1), ncol = 10), matrix(60:(100-1), ncol = 10), matrix(110:(150-1), ncol = 10)),
             list(matrix(200:(500-1), ncol = 10), matrix(600:(1000-1), ncol = 10), matrix(1100:(1500-1), ncol = 10)))
```

1. I need to subset each dataframe/matrix into two parts (by a given number of rows) and save to a new list of lists
2. Secondly, I need to extract and save a given column(s) out of every `data.frame` in a list of lists.

I have no idea how to go around doing it apart from `for()`, but I am sure it should be possible with `apply()` family of functions.

Thank you for reading

**EDIT:**

My expected output would look as follows:

```
extractedColumns <- list(list(matrix(10:(50-1), ncol = 10)[, 2], matrix(60:(100-1), ncol = 10)[, 2], matrix(110:(150-1), ncol = 10)[, 2]),
                         list(matrix(200:(500-1), ncol = 10)[, 2], matrix(600:(1000-1), ncol = 10)[, 2], matrix(1100:(1500-1), ncol = 10)[, 2]))


numToSubset <- 3
substetFrames <- list(list(list(matrix(10:(50-1), ncol = 10)["first length - numToSubset rows", ], matrix(10:(50-1), ncol = 10)["last numToSubset rows", ]), 
                           list(matrix(60:(100-1), ncol = 10)["first length - numToSubset rows", ], matrix(60:(100-1), ncol = 10)["last numToSubset rows", ]),
                                list(matrix(110:(150-1), ncol = 10)["first length - numToSubset rows", ], matrix(110:(150-1), ncol = 10)["last numToSubset rows", ])),
                      etc...)
```

It gets to look very messy, hope you can follow what I want.

Comment: this looks pretty straightforward use of `lapply()`, possibly nested.  Would you please update the post with your desired output?

Comment: Thank you. Edited my question

Comment: Desired output is not clear nor completely runnable code but pseudocode. Which one is it *extractedColumns* or *substetFrames*? And in #2, you say extract given columns but you are attempting extracted rows for `substetFrames` even using the word *rows* in psuedocode?

Comment: @Parfait: Thanks for replying. Actually I think it is quite clear, please do let me know what seems unclear to you. I want two outputs (2 questions) - subsetFrames is a list of 2 frames subset by a given rows, extractColumn is a list of columns extracted from the original data frames. It corresponds to my two questions (albeit in reversed order, if that confuses you)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use two nested `lapply`s:

```
lapply(test, function(x) lapply(x, '[', c(2, 3)))
```

Ouput:

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 11 12

[[1]][[2]]
[1] 61 62

[[1]][[3]]
[1] 111 112


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] 201 202

[[2]][[2]]
[1] 601 602

[[2]][[3]]
[1] 1101 1102
```

#### Explanation

The first `lapply` will be applied on the two lists of `test`. Each one of those two lists contain another 3. The second `lapply` will iterate over those 3 lists and subset (thats the `'['` function in the second `lapply`) columns `c(2, 3)`.

Note: In the case of a matrix `[` will subset elements 2 and 3 but the same function will subset columns when used on a data.frame.

#### Subsetting rows and columns

`lapply` is very flexible with the use of anonymous functions. By changing the code into:

```
#change rows and columns into what you need
lapply(test, function(x) lapply(x, function(y) y[rows, columns]))
```

You can specify any combination of rows or columns you want.

Comment: Perfect solution for my second question - extracting given columns of the data frames. Also really appreaciate the explanation. I had one more question - how to subtract the data frames by rows (e.g. each data frame split in half by rows and save to a new list of lists of lists of data frames)? Please if you could answer that too, I will be grateful and accept your answer.

Comment: Tried this. It works when I use `split()` on a given data frame, but when used in lapply with "x", it throws the following error:



`splitFrames <- lapply(test, function(x) split(x, c(rep(1, dim(x)[1] - 3), rep(2, 3))))
 
 Error in rep(1, dim(x)[1] - 3) : invalid 'times' argument`

Comment: I have updated the answer. The explanation is exactly the same as the one I wrote previously. Replacing rows with e.g. `1:5` and columns with `c(2,3)`, will extract first 5 rows and 2,3 columns for each of the data.frames.

Comment: `split` is not the right way to go here. Nested `lapply`s is the right way.

Comment: Okay, I think I got it. But it is only thanks to you - I have never tried using nested applies. Keep it up please, we learn a lot from people like you!

`splitFrames <- lapply(test, function(x) lapply(x, function(y) split(y, c(rep(1, dim(y)[1] - 3), rep(2, 3)))))`

Comment: DId not notice the update before I posted. Good to know another solution.

Comment: You are very welcome. The R community is growing and people are willing to help others, which is always nice :). If your actual data is not too complicated (as in the data.frames have the same structure) I would avoid the use of `split` as it creates more lists. Simple subsetting with nested `lapply`s should work fine. It takes some practice but you ll get there!

Comment: I am sorry to disturb, but I still cannot my head around the notation `lapply(x, '[', c(2, 3))` . How can I think of the '[' part? And does there exist a similar symbol doing same thing for rows?

Comment: Everything is a function in R, including `[`.  `'['(1:5, 1)` is the same as `1:5[1]`. You could do  `lapply(x, '[', 1:5, c(2, 3))`. `1:5` and `c(2,3)` are arguments passed on to `[`. There are many tutorials about the use of `lapply`, you could  benefit from. Just google how to use `lapply`.

Answer (score 1):

To piggyback @LyzandeR's answer, consider the often ignored sibling of the apply family, `rapply` that can recursively run functions on lists of vectors/matrices, returning such nested structures. Often it can compare to nested `lapply` or its variants `v/sapply`:

```
newtest1 <- lapply(test, function(x) lapply(x, '[', c(2, 3)))

newtest2 <- rapply(test, function(x) `[`(x, c(2, 3)), classes="matrix", how="list")

all.equal(newtest1, newtest2)
# [1] TRUE
```

---

Interestingly, to my amazement, `rapply` runs slower in this use case compared to nested `lapply`! Hmmmm, back to the lab I go...

```
library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(newtest1 <- lapply(test, function(x) lapply(x, '[', c(2, 3))))    
# Unit: microseconds
#     mean median     uq    max neval
# 31.92804 31.278 32.241 74.587   100

microbenchmark(newtest2 <- rapply(test, function(x) `[`(x, c(2, 3)),
                                        classes="matrix", how="list"))    
# Unit: microseconds
#    min    lq     mean median      uq    max neval
# 69.293 72.18 79.53353 73.143 74.5865 219.91   100
```

Even more interesting, is removing the `[` operator for the equivalent matrix bracketing, nested `lapply` runs even better and `rapply` even worse!

```
microbenchmark(newtest3 <- lapply(test, function(x) 
                                  lapply(x, function(y) y[c(2, 3), 1])))
# Unit: microseconds
#    min     lq     mean median     uq    max neval
# 26.947 28.391 32.00987 29.354 30.798 100.09   100

all.equal(newtest1, newtest3)
# [1] TRUE

microbenchmark(newtest4 <- rapply(test, function(x) x[c(2,3), 1], 
                                  classes="matrix", how="list"))
# Unit: microseconds
#    min     lq     mean median     uq     max neval
# 74.105 76.752 80.37076 77.955 78.918 203.549   100

all.equal(newtest2, newtest4)
# [1] TRUE
```